# Run android app in eclipse using remote source code build

Tags: android, remote-server

I have android source code on a remote server, for which I have ssh credentials. I have eclipse on my local linux machine. I want to test android apps based on the built source code on the remote server.

After compiling the source code on the server, I start the emulator via linux shell (using ssh) with the emulator command, and the emulator comes up as normal. Now I want to run my android app (on local machine) and want to select this emulator as the running device. The emulator launched from the shell does not appear in the list of running devices.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What kind of source control? git, svn..?

Answer (score 0):

Try download subversion plugin for eclipse and check out your project from eclipse. you also can check out outside eclipse and after import the project into eclipse workspace.